# How to exit default www-browser?

Tags: browser, update-alternatives

I inadvertently landed in the `www-browser` application. This is a text based web browser.

How do I exit it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`www-browser` is managed by Debian alternatives system, it it a generic name for a CLI browser to point to.

You can check which browser it currently points to by:

```
update-alternatives --display www-browser
```

In my system:

```
y% update-alternatives --display www-browser
www-browser - auto mode
  link currently points to /usr/bin/lynx
/usr/bin/lynx - priority 40
  slave www-browser.1.gz: /usr/share/man/man1/lynx.1.gz
Current 'best' version is '/usr/bin/lynx'.
```

As you can see it currently points to `lynx`.

Now i can exit `lynx` hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>.

**EDIT:**

As you are using `w3m` you can press <kbd>q</kbd> and then <kbd>y</kbd> to exit.

Comment: In my case, the browser is w3m. Do you know how to exit that one? ctrl-C doesn't ...

Comment: @drevicko yes..press "q" and then `"y"

Answer (score 2):

Closing the terminal window it runs in (just like closing any other window) should terminate the application, unless it was started with a command line option to ignore HUP signals or continue independent of the parent process.

Comment: Another similar option is to identify the browser in top/htop and kill it from there. This way, whatever launched it (ipython notebook in my case) is left running.

Comment: If it was started from a GUI app, or opened in a new window from a terminal app or shell, closing the terminal window running the browser or other app won't generally close the app that launched it.

Comment: True enough, but ipython notebook (or jupyter notebook as its now called) doesn't lanuch a new terminal. If you're in an ssh session, you wouldn't have that luxury either (unless you're using byobu or some such). Still, closing the window/terminal can be a good solution in many cases (: